# How to place logo over the side of a truck, using Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, transform

I got Photoshop CS6

Images shown below

[image: http://s3.postimg.org/aakyyogar/Untitled_1.jpg]

Comment: Hi user41631, thanks for your question. As Scott says, it's nice to show us where in the process you are stuck and what you have tried. Besides, googling 'logo perspective photoshop tutorial' yields almost 15 **million** results.

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved using `Perspective Transform`

1. Select your the Logo layer
2. Hit <kbd>Control/Apple</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> to enter transform mode
3. Make sure the `Bounding Box` is visible, you should be able to see handles on the edges and corners of the logo layer. If the bounding box isn't visible, check your view settings.
4. Right click on the object and select `Perspective` from the menu
5. Dragging the handles will now give a perspective effect. When you're happy with the transformation, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit transform mode. Holding <kbd>Control</kbd> when dragging a handle will stop the other handles from moving.

For your image, you'll probably need to move the top left and bottom left handles the most. Try to make the top edge and bottom edge of the logo match the top edge and bottom edge of the Trailer.

It's also worth making sure that your Logo layer contains just the logo. if there are pixels outside of the logo itself these will affect the perspective when transforming.

Answer (score 1):

First of all place your logo as a new layer (or shape) over your truck image. Then you can use free transform tool <kbd>Ctrl/Option</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to do perspective distortion (via <kbd>Control/Option</kbd>-dragging corner nodes).

Comment: Tried that. But the other side moves on doing so :(

Comment: oh! you need to hold down Ctrl before dragging corner :)